# Elegant way to show an array list of int

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

Hi everyone I am working with a `LazyVGrid` on my **SwiftUI** project for displaying a list of times ...

This is the array of hours

```
let hoursList = [09, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 17, 18, 18]
    
let columns = Array(repeating: GridItem(), count: 4)
LazyVGrid(columns: columns, alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {
    ForEach(viewModel.hoursList) { hours in
        Text("\(hours)")
    }
    ///////////
    // more elegant way to get the times as in the array?
    //////////
}
```

As you can see in the array there are times that repeat for example **10 - 10, 11 - 11**

Is there a more elegant way to get an array like the one above but without specifying every number? instead of directly using '`hourList`' can I reach my goal using a more elegant way?

Comment: What's the pattern here? Why does every number occur two times in the list but not for 9 and 13?

Comment: Do you mean `ForEach(viewModel.hoursList) { Text("\($0)") }`? For the hoursList, it represent a start/end? So maybe using a `struct Hour { let start: Int, let end: Int }` instead might make more sense... Then, `ForEach(viewModel.hoursList) { Text("\($0.start) - \($0.end)") }`?

Comment: @Sweeper because I need to display 10:00 am and 10:30 am and so on for all the others .. for now I was thinking of using this scheme to avoid using an array like the one in my post because it doesn't look very nice. 

`ForEach(9..<19) { hours in
              
  if hours >= 10 {
                    Text("\(hours):00")
                    Text("\(hours):30")
                }
                else {
                    Text("\(hours):30")
                }
            }`

Comment: Why are you keeping it as `Ints`, as opposed to `Dates`? Are these just the headers for a schedule, or what? I am having trouble envisioning what you want this to look like on screen.

Comment: @Larme thanks you are always very kind to answer my questions! .. my problem is that I wanted to try not to use an array as I did in my post because it doesn't seem very elegant to me to create an array with repeated numbers inside it

Comment: @Yrb I'm trying to create a time selector for the user using a LazyVGrid

Comment: But this is not the actual data, it is just for the users' view? If so, then yes, set an array with the duplicate entries, but I would put them in as `Strings` to be exactly how you want them. `let hoursList = ["09:00", "10:00", "10:30", ...]. Making it more complex simply makes another place where you can introduce a bug.

Comment: @Yrb Yes these are given only to display to the user because when the user selects one of these times he creates a new date with the selected time (I create a new date with a date already selected previously and then set the time based on the user selection through the use of calendar.date (bySettingHour) Is that right as I thought I'd do?

Comment: That seems reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Hour & Minute should Convert into Number System, so
`HH`:`mm` from Clock will be (`HH`).(`mm/60`) in Numeral

> 02:00 is 2.0
> 06:30 is 6.5
> 08:45 is 8.75
> 15:55 is 15.916666...

```
extension Double {
    var minute: Int { Int(self * 60) - Int(self)*60 }
}

let hoursList = [9.5, 10.0, 10.5, 12, 12.5, 14.5, 15, 16, 17, 17.75, 18, 18.25]

let columns = Array(repeating: GridItem(), count: 4)
LazyVGrid(columns: columns, alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {
    ForEach(viewModel.hoursList) { hour in
        Text(String(format: "%d : %.2d", Int(hour), hour.minute))
    }
}
```